# sinon is not mocking import function

Tags: node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have the following code. Sinon failed to mock doSomething() and printing actual string instead of 'hello'

```
//file.js

import { doSomething } from 'my-npm-package';
module.exports = () => doSomething();
```

This is the test file:

```
//file.spec.js

import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as apis from 'my-npm-package';
import someFunction from '../file';

describe('TEST', () => {
  let stub;
  beforeEach(() => {
    stub = sinon.stub(apis, 'doSomething').returns('hello');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('test', async () => {
    someFunction();
    expect(stub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: This works as expected for me.  It might be an issue with compilation, are you using `webpack` or doing anything unusual with `babel`?

Comment: when i use `sinon.assert.calledOnce(apis.doSomething);` i get ` AssertError: function doSomething(_x5, _x6) {
        return _ref2.apply(this, arguments);
    } is not stubbed
`

Comment: using `--require babel-polyfill`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your module.exports, you'll notice that there isn't a named function. If you set your module like below, you'll notice that `apis` will have a property on it called `doSomething`, which you'll be able to stub.

`module.exports = { doSomething }`

Comment: tried it. didn't make any difference. still the stub is ignored it seems

Comment: well, when i manually run apis() or console.log it, i can see that it's available and working file. so dont think its an issue with not having named exports